# how to search a folder for images that contain the keyword in their name in php

Tags: php, jquery, html

im making a photo gallery and i want to make a search bar which displays all the images that have the searched keyword in their name. i have stored my images in a folder (NOT DATABASE, IN A FOLDER).
i have made the search bar  but i cant get the PHP part working. do i need ajax or jquery ?
this is my current code which returns nothing when i press search. not even the test " eco 'hello' " part.

```
    ?php
$dir = "/uploads";
// Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            if($file == $_POST['searching']){
// replace this line with eco <img> line
                echo('<a href="'.$dir . $file.'">'. $file .'</a>'."\n");
                 echo "hello" ;
                 }
         }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
?>
```

i want to get a list of the images with keyword (searching) in the name.

Comment: [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) will do this easily

Answer (score -1):

It could be as simple as replacing `if($file == $_POST['searching']){` with `if (false !== strpos($file, $_POST['searching'])){`.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `scandir()` to get an array of files in the directory and then loop through it:

```
$dir_array=scandir($dir);
foreach($dir_array as $file){
  if($file == $_POST['searching']){
  // open file etc. here
  echo('<a href="'.$dir . $file.'">'. $file .'</a>'."\n");
  }
}
```